# SpyOn a Angular Custom Filter

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'd like to know how I can SpyOn a custom filter. For example, my code is

```
$scope.getLink = function() {
                    return $filter('BaseUrl')('/test.html');
                };
```

I want to spyOn $filter('BaseUrl') in my Jasmine test so that it returns a string. something like this

```
spyOn($filter,'BaseUrl').andReturn('http://localhost');
expect(scope.getLink()).toEqual('http://localhost/test.html');
```

How can I do this.

Thanks in advance,